# Register_Post_Type URL Rewrite

Tags: wordpress

I have made a new section for posts on my wordpress site, but I am having trouble rewriting the URL's as they are all messed up right now, here is my code, can anyone push me in the right direction?

```
    register_post_type('services', array(
'label' => __('Services'),
'singular_label' => __('Services'),
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => false,
'query_var' => false,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields' )
));
```

Right now my URL currently looks like this...

http://examplesite.com/?post_type=services&p=52

and I want it to look like this

http://examplesite.com/services/postname

Can anyone help me?!

Comment: Have you modified the permalinks under the wordpress settings in the admin interface?

Comment: Yes, custom structure: /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: and you're sure that's actually hitting your .htaccess file? might want to make sure WP can successfully write to it.

Comment: Read about flushing rewrites : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation

Comment: When i turn it to true, I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in /wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 51

Comment: I dont understand the rewrite flushes, can someone explain briefly?

Comment: You should hook **`register_post_type`** within **`init`** action !

Answer (score 2):

Change `'rewrite' => false` to `'rewrite' => true`!

Or you could be more explicit:

```
'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'services'),
```

Comment: When i turn it to true, I get this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in /wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 51

Comment: Try the ol' plugin deactivation trick: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/30-upgrade-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-add_rewrite_tag-on-a-non-ob

Comment: Sounds like a Wordpress update issue to me. What version are you using, and how did you install it?

Comment: I am using 3.4.2, and I upgraded from a previous version

Comment: This thread helped me rewrite my URLs, but then the pages that got rewritten couldnt be found:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-34-update-comes-with-fatal-error

Comment: @onei0120 You should hook **`register_post_type`** within **`init`** action !